# How to know which docker image I am using here?

Tags: docker

Once upon a time I spent half a day testing several nginx-ssl-proxy images until I found one that worked fine for me. As you can see that was 4 months ago:

```
# docker images -a
REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx-ssl-proxy                         latest              b143510d7487        4 months ago        182.8 MB
```

Today I wanted to use that image again and search the web for its documentation (probably a github page). But as a "docker search nginx-ssl-proxy" shows there are about 20 docker images named nginx-ssl-proxy. How do I know out which one I am using right now?

```
# docker search nginx-ssl-proxy
NAME                                       DESCRIPTION                                     STARS     OFFICIAL   AUTOMATED
mapero/nginx-proxy-ssl                     Modified version of nginx-proxy from Jason...   4                    [OK]
ployst/nginx-ssl-proxy                     https://github.com/ployst/docker-nginx-ssl...   2                    [OK]
aaaler/nginx-ssl-proxy                     Simple nginx microservice proxing https re...   2                    [OK]
codedevote/nginx-ssl-proxy-rancher         A docker nginx reverse proxy with ssl term...   2                    [OK]
pavlov/nginx-ssl-proxy                     Nginx reverse proxy for SSL termination in...   1                    [OK]
danieldent/nginx-ssl-proxy                 SSL Front-End Proxy With Automatic Free Ce...   1                    [OK]
centurylinklabs/nginx-ssl-proxy            A few adjustments to the nginx image to ac...   0                    [OK]
etc etc etc
```

Is there any docker command that shows more details about an image like the full name, tags etc? I even tried searching in /var/lib/docker but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use docker inspect

```
docker inspect --help

Usage:  docker inspect [OPTIONS] CONTAINER|IMAGE|TASK [CONTAINER|IMAGE|TASK...]

Return low-level information on a container, image or task
```

it will show you all the Created date,env variable,cmd, entrypoint, layers and much more